# Php "load view" to send it with database result to jquery post, then display on html

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I want to send back to a jquery post method a "view", html code (not the whole page, just a div or a table) with a database result, so then I can display with the jquery html method on the page where is the original form.
I remember that you can do that with Codeigniter (and json), you use "load-view" and add to it data from your database and the view will execute the php code with that data; but I'm not using any framework, it is possible to do this?
The only solution until now for me is to display in my php file that I send the post all the results in a variable with html code and then make a echo as a response, but when you have to display a lot of rows, it is very complicated.

This is an example:

```
            $html = "
        <table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id='servicios'>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Tipo</th>
              <th>Proveniencia</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
              <th>Descripción</th>
              <th>Valor</th>
              <th>Iva</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
            <tbody>";
                $i = 1;
                foreach($resultado as $print){

      $html .= "<tr class='dynamic-row' data-href='#' data-id='{$print['id_servicio']}'>
                  <th scope='row'>$i</th>
                  <td>{$print['nombre_tipo']}</td>";
        $html .= "<td>";if($print['proveniencia'] == 'interno') $html .= "Interno";else $html .= "Externo";$html .= "</td>";
        $html .= "<td>{$print['nombre_servicio']}</td>
                  <td>{$print['descripcion_servicio']}</td>
                  <td>";if(!empty($print['valor_servicio'])) $html .= "{$print['valor_servicio']}";$html .= "</td>
                  <td>";if($print['iva_servicio']) $html .= "Sí";else $html .= "No";$html .= "</td>
                </tr>";
                $i++;
                }
  $html .= "</tbody>
        </table>";
```

So I'm looking for a better and simplier solution.

PS: I perfectly know how to use jquery post, and php with PDO. So my only problem is the one I mention.

Comment: Clarification question: what's you end game here? What's the final product you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Does the code shown work and you just want help making it cleaner? Not sure either what the issue is

Comment: I write that code just to show how complicated is to send the html part from php with the data from the database. What I want is what I said: load a view AND the array with DB result and that the view execute php code with that data.